# Program Window Lock in Tkinter

Tags: python, locking, window, size, tkinter

I was curious if there was a way to make my program in python to have a locked size. What I mean by that is that you can't stretch the window to make it larger or smaller etc. Hopefully I've made myself clear and hopefully something of the like is possible in Python. Thanks

Comment: Why would you ever want to do this? For the best user experience, the user should be able to make the window whatever size they want.

Answer (score 4):

```
root.resizable(0, 0) #or root.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)
```

Easy as a piece of pie!

Or you could do the following:

```
root.minsize(min_x, min_y)
root.maxsize(max_x, max_y)
```

You will still be able to grab the side of the window but you can't stretch it.